# jQuery validate -How do I remove a specific error message without removing any other error messages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**See**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edaloicaro18/K2tv4/41/)

I'm trying to remove **only a specific error message (*"Select a department"*)**, when a different option to "External" is selected from the select list **"Role"**, since only when a user role is **"External"** I need to specify which department that user belongs to.

I've only been able to remove the error style using `removeClass("error")`, but even after I've removed that class, the error message is still display and it only disappears if I attempt to submit the form and that's not what I want, what I want to do is to make that error message (**"Select a department"**) disappear **as soon as another user role is selected**(a role different to "external" of course)

**In order for you to understand me more easily I have put up a** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edaloicaro18/K2tv4/41/).

I really hope you can help me out

Comment: You're fiddle is not clear, i don't see the error messages nor the role dropdown you're talking about. Are you asking about removing error message that appear from using jquery validate?

Comment: Wrong jsFiddle. Words are in Spanish and there's no `Role`, just these: `COMPANY DATE DOC TYPE NUMBER SERIES TYPE UNIT EXPENDITURE`

Comment: sorry, the jsFiddle doesn't show your validation code. At first glance I' wondering why "select a department" does appear. Can you modify the validation not to check departments if Role is "External"? Removing the message later should be *plan B* ... or C

Comment: @Majid -Sorry I made a mistake ,but now it's OK. Please take another look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `department.next().hide();` after the line that disables the select. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K2tv4/45/).

```
...
role.change(function() {
    if (role.val()=="EU"){
        ...
    } else{
        department.removeClass("error");
        department.attr("disabled", true);    
        department.next().hide();
        $("#password").focus();
    }
});
...
```

Comment: thnx a million Majid that really worked :D I just want to ask you if you would have done the same : 1. `department.removeClass("error");` and 2. `department.next().hide();`. Or what would you have done ??

Comment: I see, I didn't marked the answer as accepted before because I preferred to wait for your opinion or that of others.Thank you for the explanation. It's clear to me now